# List the largest possible cuboids inside a 16x16x16 matrix

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

I have a 16x16x16 cubic matrix containing `[0;k]`  possible values I would like to be able to list the largest possible cuboids inside that matrix where every value is the same for this cuboid.

An iterative "expansion" algorithm could do the trick, but given there are 4096 cells, that would be way to expensive to do.

There are similar questions, but they only address a two-dimensional matrix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that by "cuboid", you mean that it must be the same size in all 3 dimensions.

In that case, the size of the largest cuboid with maximal point (x,y,z) can be calculated from the sizes of the largest cuboids with maximal points (x-1,y,z), (x,y-1,z), (x,y,z-1), (x-1,y-1,z), (x-1,y,z-1), (x,y-1,z-1), and (x-1, y-1, z-1).

Just process the points in sum(x,y,z) order, and then, if all those neighboring points have the same value, then largest_cuboid_size(x,y,z) = 1 + min(largest_cuboid_size(..for each neighbor with a smaller coordinate...))

EDIT: Since you do NOT require all sides the same length, you would need to keep track of multiple data per cell in order to use this method.  For example, you could calculate the maximum box size for each (width,height).

You can still calculate the entries for each cell from its neighbors, but there can be up to 256 entries per cell, so it's a longer process.

That's up to 16^5 (1048576) values that have to be calculated to solve the whole problem.  Should take much less than a second, so maybe it's fast enough for your purpose.

Comment: I meant a rectangular box, but this special case with cubes could be used anyway as a first attempt

Comment: That complicates things.  I'll add something for rectangular boxes, but it won't be as fast.

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking of using several algorithms that could be efficient for specific scenarios and then falling back to a generic (and slower) algorithm if the first one wouldn't yell satisfying results. What do you mean by "calmculating the entries". Also, " For example, you could calculate the maximum box size for each (width,height)" (did you forget depth). I would also rather avoid collision (but AABB checks should do the trick easily)

Comment: So I implemented a very "dumb" algorithm that seems to work on most test cases however, for 16*16*16 cube it takes up to 8s